# Where GitLab CE displays commit status?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ce

GitLab has an [api to set commit status](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/commits.html#post-the-build-status-to-a-commit) and Jenkins has a plugin that sets this status.

Now I have a stupid question: where my user can see this status is displayed in GitLab interface?

Screenshots are welcomed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: There's a checkbox top right]

The green checkbox appears near the commit id in the top right of the screen.